# How can we make the fields unique in Query Manager in PeopleSoft?

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-query

How can we make the fields unique in Query Manager in PeopleSoft ?

Comment: Questions on how to operate computer programs are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Each record requires unique fields. So for each record within a query, the fields will be unique by definition. If you have multiple records, however, you might have the same field twice. For example, a query with multiple records with descr will have multiple descr fields in the output. By default, they will all share the same label in the output, so the column labels will not be unique (by default). You can change this from the fields tab. Click the Edit button next to the field you would like to change. You will then see a Heading Text and a Unique Field Name. You may change both of them, although the unique field name is already unique across the columns in the query, and is usually the record alias.field, for example, B.DESCR.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the properties of the query
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKKnO.png)

Check Distinct in the Properties Page
[Check Distinct in the Properties Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFxtZ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).